# Google play game services auto sign out after some time

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have implemented auto sign in for Google play game services in my Android game and having the following issue.

**Step1:** Open the app first time with Internet connection. User is signed in with the small sign in dialogue.

**Step2:** Close the app, stop internet connection, again open the app and the user is still signed in.

**Step3:** Now close the app and open it after 3-4 hours without internet connection. Sign in is failing with error `Couldn’t connect to server` and next time its again signing in the user with the small sign in dialogue which should be for the first time. So basically its signed out somehow.

This issue is did not happen before I released the app.

The only change I did is switched ON the `Save Game` option in Google Play Game Services before publishing but I don’t think that can cause this problem.